# How to update email template (notification) using Shopify API?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

Under Settings -> Notifications, it is possible to edit the content of all notification (order confirmation, order canceled, order refund, etc.). I am trying to find a way to change the template using the Shopify API. I have been looking at their documentation and I cannot find anything. Am I missing something?

How to update email template (notification) using Shopify API? Thank you!

Comment: Nope! You are not missing something. Usually if you are not able to find an API endpoint to something you are trying to do in Shopify, that means it's not publicly available.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. There is no endpoint for access to that. Just login to your shop and change those things using Shopify itself. They spent a fortune making their own email editing service, so that is why you likely won't get to play in that sandbox anytime soon.